# Search Results Web results Collapsible Navbar

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to click on a collapsible nav bar in selenium webdriver?

```html
<div id="termsandconditions" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="form-group" app-field-wrapper="terms_text">
            <textarea id="terms_text" name="terms_text" class="form-control tinymce" rows="4"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried it through XPath but element not clickable `at(x,y)` arrives.

Comment: Can you show what you have done ? The above is not clear - which line would you except to be clickable ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try clicking with Javascript to bypass the `ElementNotClickable` error you are seeing:

```
menu = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'panel-collapse')]")

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", menu)
```

Some elements do not accept regular Selenium `click()` method, so we use Javascript occasionally to work around these special elements.
Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: What kind of elements have you found where the regular Selenium `click()` method does not work?

Comment: I have seen issues with `click()` not working when trying to click `div` elements. `click()` usually works on `button`, `a`, `input`, and a few others. But clicking `div` gives issues sometimes -- not always however. There is no catch-all case where you know you need to use Javascript. It always depends on the web page you are automating, and what the behavior is like. I try one method, if it does not work, then I try the other.

Comment: The only times I've had issues like the one your describing is when the element I'm trying to click is off the screen, or is covered up by another element.  It sounds like what you're doing could work in those situations though, if making the element be available for Selenium to click on is not feasible.

Comment: @Phil these are also cases, yes. In some React or Javascript-heavy applications, I have seen cases where a perfectly visible element still throws the error.

Comment: I see.  Are there any publicly available sites you've written automation against that display this behavior?  I'd be interested in seeing this happen.

Comment: This was a private QA environment, so unable to share -- in production, custom HTML themes were applied on top so QA and PROD web pages were completely different (testing nightmare). But the application was written in React.js with a mixture of Ext and Angular JS frameworks. I ran into cases where clicking `button` would fail, because a hidden `div` element was obscuring -- visually, the `button` looked clickable, but hidden elements higher up in the tree would cause visibility issues, making Javascript click necessary in some cases.

Comment: Oh, ok.  It sounds like this is similar to the situation I was thinking of, where a div is covering something you want to click, the only difference being that the end user would not be able to tell, because the covering div is invisible.